# #1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf 32 croatian ci' how solve this error in phpmyadmin wamp server

Tags: mysql

my create table code is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `current_sabhay` (
  `current_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `year_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `desc` varchar(225) CHARACTER SET utf32 COLLATE utf32_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`current_id`,`parment_id`),
  KEY `year_id` (`year_id`),
  KEY `current_sabhay_ibfk_2` (`parment_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Comment: Which version of mysql do you use?

Comment: First thing to check would be [SHOW COLLATION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-collation.html) to find out which collations your db currently supports.

Comment: i am using   mysql 5.0.10